# Agrupar consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql

La siguiente tabla muestra el resultado que obtengo de un query:

```
SELECT pm.post_id, pm.meta_value
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN terms t ON p.post_title = t.name
LEFT JOIN term_relationships tr ON t.term_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN postmeta pm ON tr.object_id = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_type = 'lrooms' AND p.post_author = '1' AND pm.meta_key IN ('_appointment_timestamp', '_appointment_timeslot', '_appointment_guest_name', '_appointment_guest_surname', '_appointment_guest_email')
ORDER BY pm.meta_id DESC
```

| post_id | meta_value |
| --- | --- |
| 9247 | 1730-1800 |
| 9247 | 1609608600 |
| 9247 | correo@gmail.com |
| 9247 | Correa |
| 9247 | Jose Dario |
| 9245 | 1130-1200 |
| 9245 | 1609414200 |
| 9245 | correo@gmail.com |
| 9245 | Pinedo |
| 9245 | Andres |

Quisiera agrupar/concatenar los valores de la columna meta_value de la siguiente manera:

| post_id | meta_value |
| --- | --- |
| 9247 | 1730-1800;1609608600;correo@gmail.com;Correa;Jose Dario |
| 9245 | 1130-1200;1609414200;correo@gmail.com;Pinedo;Andres |

¿Como puedo hacer esto posible?

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo al respecto?

Comment: Saludos. Da un vistazo a `GROUP_CONCAT` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: Muchas gracias @RobertoLeOr era justo lo que necesitaba. En el select agregue esto: GROUP_CONCAT(pm.meta_value ORDER BY pm.meta_key DESC SEPARATOR ';') AS 'meta_value'

Comment: ¿Ya resolviste tu problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Problema resuelto!

Teniendo en cuenta la respuesta de [@RobertoLeOr](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/177464/robertoleor) ajuste mi query de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT pm.post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(pm.meta_value ORDER BY pm.meta_key DESC SEPARATOR ';') AS 'meta_value'
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN terms t ON p.post_title = t.name
LEFT JOIN term_relationships tr ON t.term_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN postmeta pm ON tr.object_id = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_type = 'lrooms' AND p.post_author = '1' AND pm.meta_key IN ('_appointment_timestamp', '_appointment_timeslot', '_appointment_guest_name', '_appointment_guest_surname', '_appointment_guest_email')
ORDER BY pm.meta_id DESC
```

El ajuste en especial fue el siguiente, justo en el select de mí query:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(pm.meta_value ORDER BY pm.meta_key DESC SEPARATOR ';') AS 'meta_value'
```

Y pude obtener el resultado deseado.